Is there an algorithm to find the greatest lower bound type of two types?
I have been reading Peyton Jones'  Practical Type Inference for Arbitrary-Rank Types and I am working with type inference and higher-ranked polymorphism, and trying to determine the least common type of two types. For example, given two subsumptions:

(A < (forall a. a -> Int))
(A < (forall a. a -> Bool))

I’d like to determine a type A that is the "greatest lower bound" of these two. One can suggest that A could be forall a. a -> a, but I wanted to know if there exists an algorithm for this.
In the following case:

(A < ((forall a. a) -> Int))
(A < ((forall a. a) -> Bool))

A should be ((forall a. a) -> (forall a. a)).
My initial thought is an algorithm that compares the structures of the types and, when encountering differing specific types, replaces them with a polymorphic type. In the first case it had to be replaced with a, while in the second it had to be replaced with (forall a. a). I'm not certain if there can be an algorithm for this.
Is there a known algorithm or method in type theory or type inference that handles this sort of problem?

What does "most common least type" mean?

@DanielWagner Given two types, I am naming the type that is less than both given types (but is more among all the types that is less than both), most common least type.

You might be looking for anti-unification.

Is there a reason to believe that there even is a most common least type? It seems very plausible to me that there are two (or more) incomparable types that are less than both.

Maybe the phrase you want is “greatest lower bound”?

@NaïmFavier Yes, Thank you.

@DanielWagner yes there will be multiple but I need the greatest one.

@DavidYoung yes maybe that is a better word. Thank you.

@NisNis Right, but I am suggesting that you may be in trouble, because there may be no (unique) greatest one. (I don't know if this is true, I only warn you that it isn't obvious straight away.) As a related example, in standard Haskell every term has a unique most-general type. That is, there is a type you can give the term that generalizes every other type you can give it. But once you add rank-2 or rank-3 polymorphism, you lose that property: many terms can be given two (polymorphic) types neither of which generalizes the other.

@DanielWagner you mean for example if I have A < (forall a.a) -> (forall a.a) and A < forall a.(a -> Int) then neither is more general than the other and the structure even is not the same so anti-unification algorithm that has been suggested previously, would set A = (forall b.b)

There are situations where there is no greatest lower bound: if you consider constraints/type classes, then forall a. C a => a is a common subtype of Int and Bool for any constraint C satisfied by both Int and Bool. You can then try to join constraints like forall a. (C1 a, C2 a) => a, but that only works for a closed world of finitely many constraints, whereas type classes are open world and you can even have a family of classes indexed by Nat (class C n a; instance C 0 Int; instance C Zero Bool; instance C n a => C (Succ n) a)

What's the greatest lower bound of forall y x. (y -> x) -> x and forall x. ((forall y. y) -> x) -> x?

@Li-yaoXia That is right. Thank you.
